# Pass a string from <form> to controller using ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm doing this little tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-2/how-do-i/creating-a-tasklist-application-with-aspnet-mvc

But somehow he's passing a string back to the controller.  But I can't get mine to pass a string back.  What am I missing?

Create.aspx

```html
<form method="post" action="/Home/CreateNew">
    <label for="task">Task:</label>
    <input type="text" name="task" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add Task" /> 
</form>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult CreateNew(object obj ) // <-- expecting a string but getting an object.
{
  string whattype = obj.GetType().ToString(); //just an obj, expecting a string
  //add to DB next
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC is convention based - the form element name is `task` so that should be the parameter name:

```
public ActionResult CreateNew(string task ) //<-- expecting a string but getting an object.
{
  string whattype = obj.GetType().ToString(); //just an obj, expecting a string
  //add to DB next
}
```